# Knockout Subscribe to child property from parent

Tags: knockout.js

How do i subscribe to a child property on a parent model? I need to update child properties when a value changes i.e.

```
Item A
  ChildItem 1 
     ID
     Selected
     HasValue
  ChildItem 2
     ID
     Selected
     HasValue
Item B
  ChildItem 1
     ID
     Selected
     HasValue
  ChildItem 2
     ID
     Selected
     HasValue
```

When Selected on any ChildItem changes (e.g. 1), I want to update HasValue for that ChildItem (1) on all Items (Item A and Item B).

Comment: Can you add what you have tried to your question please and provide details of the issues you are having, otherwise you're just asking users to write all the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use ko.subscribable()?

See here for details - http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html